# node-gyp not including header files

Tags: c++, build, binding, node-gyp

I have been working on a C++ addon using node-gyp and every time I try to build I run into the problem of:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost_1_74_0/boost/pro
perty_tree/ptree.hpp': No such file or directory
```

I do not understand why I am running into this problem as I included the two header files as sources in my binding.gyp file:

```
{
    "targets":[
        {
            "target_name": "water",
            "sources": ["watercpp.cpp", "boost_1_74_0/boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp", "boost_1_74_0/boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp"],
            "include_dirs": [
              "boost_1_74_0/boost/propety_tree",
              "boost_1_74_0",
            ],
            'cflags!': [ '-fno-exceptions' ],
            'cflags_cc!': [ '-fno-exceptions' ]
        },
    ]
}
```

I have the two files included in my C++ file at the top as:

```
#include <boost_1_74_0/boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost_1_74_0/boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
```

I am new to node-gyp and C++ and would appreciate it if anyone could give me some guidance in how to get rid of this error. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe boost is not in the root folder of your storage. Your sources and your include directories are in conflict. `boost_1_74_0/boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp` means the `boost_1_74_0` folder is in your current project folder. `/boost_1_74_0` means it's in the root folder of your system.

Comment: @drescherjm That is correct, `boost_1_74_0` is in my current project folder so I have it as that in binding.gyp and my C++ file.

Comment: Then remove the / before `boost_1_74_0` in your include paths. `/` means absolute path in your OS (meaning its in the root of your filesystem)

Comment: @drescherjm I did that and updated my binding.gyp above and I still run into the same error.

Comment: Verify that the header exists in the relative path that is given in the error. The path will be relative based on the project folder.

Comment: @drescherjm This was the problem. I had to change the include path in the C++ file. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You spelled the path name wrong in the first element of the include_dirs array. Should be "property_tree". You spelled "property" as "propety".